# Why code coverage not 100%? pytest-cov

Tags: python, code-coverage, pytest-cov

Why am I not getting 100% code coverage?!

All methods are tested...

How the code coverage percentage is calculated?

CODE

```
import os

def get_root_dir():
    return os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.sep, os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), '../../'))


def get_coverage_report_dir():
    return os.path.join(os.path.sep, get_root_dir(), 'coverage_report')
```

TEST

```
import unittest

class TestPaths(unittest.TestCase):

def test_paths(self):

    import src.utils.paths as paths
    self.assertTrue(paths.get_root_dir().endswith('myproject'))
    self.assertTrue(paths.get_root_dir() in paths.get_coverage_report_dir() and paths.get_coverage_report_dir().endswith('coverage_report'))
```

REPORT

```
---------- coverage: platform win32, python 2.7.14-final-0 -----------
Name                               Stmts   Miss  Cover
------------------------------------------------------
src\utils\__init__.py                  0      0   100%
src\utils\example_util_module.py       2      0   100%
src\utils\paths.py                     5      3    40%
------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                                  7      3    57%
```

Comment: Show the report.

Comment: done! please see @JonathonReinhart

Comment: Use the `--cov-report html` argument for a  complete per-line report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The html output will show you the missing lines

`pytest --cov=paths --cov-report=html`

Then open index.html from the newly created htmlcov folder.

Here is a video demonstrating achieving 100 percent test coverage.

https://youtu.be/7BJ_BKeeJyM

[image: 100% Code Coverage in Python]